# np.c_ returning a row vector, instead of columns

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, linear-regression

I am trying to write a linear/polynomial regression.

I am trying to engineer my features for a third order polynomial from hand rather than using, for example, scikit-learn.

I've imported data from a CSV file and converted this data into a row vector. Now I am trying to create a matrix with three columns (original feature, feature squared, feature cubed).

I was hoping to use numpy.c_ for this, however instead of creating a matrix with three columns I get one (very) long row vector.

The screenshot illustrates what I am trying to do and how I would expect it to behave(the short section with x and X) and what it is doing instead (the section with francis_guide_vane_pos and francis_[...]_engineered)
I am using Python v. 3.11.4

```py
# what I expected to happen
x = np.arange(0,20,1)
X = np.c_[x, x**2, x**3]
print(x, x.shape)
print(X, X.shape)

# what is actually happning
francis_guide_vane_pos_engineered = np.c_[francis_guide_vane_pos, francis_guide_vane_pos**2, francis_guide_vane_pos**3]
print(francis_guide_vane_pos, francis_guide_vane_pos.shape)
print(francis_guide_vane_pos_engineered, francis_guide_vane_pos_engineered.shape)
```

Result:

```
[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19] (20,)
[[   0    0    0]
 [   1    1    1]
 [   2    4    8]
 [   3    9   27]
 [   4   16   64]
 [   5   25  125]
 [   6   36  216]
 [   7   49  343]
 [   8   64  512]
 [   9   81  729]
 [  10  100 1000]
 [  11  121 1331]
 [  12  144 1728]
 [  13  169 2197]
 [  14  196 2744]
 [  15  225 3375]
 [  16  256 4096]
 [  17  289 4913]
 [  18  324 5832]
 [  19  361 6859]] (20, 3)

[[89.8 89.8 89.7 ... 14.8 14.8 14.8]] (1, 286996)
[[  89.8     89.8     89.7   ... 3241.792 3241.792 3241.792]] (1, 860988)
```

[Screenshot of expected result and achieved result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6lKu.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. As per [this post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors), please provide code and results as text, not images of text.

Comment: In the test case `x` has shape (20,).  It's 1d.  In the problem case the shape is (1,n).  It is already 2d, so the result is (1,3*n).  It is joining columns, `n` of them 3 times.  Try using `francis_guide_vane_pos[0]` so its (n,) shaped.  Or `francis_guide_vane_pos.T` (n,1) shaped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that in your first example, `x` is a **1-dimensional** array of shape `(20,)`. You stack these using `np.c_` to get a `(20, 3)` array.

In the second case, `francis_guide_vane_pos` is a **2-dimensional** array of shape `(1, 286996)`. To stack this as columns, either transpose the array first, or [squeeze it](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.squeeze.html) into a 1-dimensional array:

```
>>> arr = np.c_[francis_guide_vane_pos.T, francis_guide_vane_pos.T**2, francis_guide_vane_pos.T**3]
>>> print(arr.shape) # (286996, 3)
```

or

```
>>> francis_guide_vane_pos = francis_guide_vane_pos.squeeze()
>>> arr = np.c_[francis_guide_vane_pos, francis_guide_vane_pos**2, francis_guide_vane_pos**3]
>>> print(arr.shape) # (286996, 3)
```

---

**Why does stacking the 2-d array give the *"wrong"* result?**

According to the [docs for `np.c_`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.c_.html),

> arrays will be stacked along their last axis after being upgraded to at least 2-D with 1’s post-pended to the shape

Since `francis_guide_vane_pos` (and its elementwise square and cube arrays) were already 2-d, they were simply stacked along the last axis, i.e. more columns were added.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer!

I converted `francis_guide_vane_pos` from a row in a (multiple row) CSV table and transposed it. Is a row from a CSV-file always automatically a 2D array? Is there a clean way to extract just the row as a 1D array, or is `.squeeze()` generally the way to do it?

Comment: @Felix How did you read the csv file?

Comment: I am using `pd.read_csv` to read the csv file. I then drop some not needed coloums using `.drop([])` and finally use `.to_numpy()` to convert it to the array. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think you can just extract the column using `df["col_name"]` and then `.to_numpy()` will give a 1d array